# Can I get the current HTML from a sidebar in a Google Apps Script code file?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-addon

I writing a Google Apps Script (Sheet Add-on), and I'd like to get the HTML of the currently displayed sidebar back to the server-side script. The reason is that I'm making a template-based system where the HTML of the side bar may have come from a range of possible templates, but all of the templates have the same callback function back to the server to make writing them easier. So the common callback function on the server-side needs to be able to determine what HTML it was called from.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: If my understanding is correct, how about using [XMLSerializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLSerializer)?

Comment: Why does your server function need to know the client side structure - pass the relevant information (like an HTMLElement) as a user object so the client-side success handler knows the where the request originated.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need all the HTML? Or just enough information to know which template was used? When you load the templates initially you can store some metadata about what template was used in, for instance, an HTML element.
Something like `<...data-template-type="template 7">`

When you make the call to the server, grab that information from the HTML element and provide it as an argument.

Hope I understood the question and what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yeah, I think that might do it; I'll give it a go. Indeed I don't need the full html - if I can tell which template was used I can pull the html from that on the server side.

Comment: Hmm; the addMetaTag function (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output#addMetaTag(String,String) ) doesn't work as it's restricted to a couple of special meta tags. I guess I could add it directly to the HTML and parse that client-side, or try to add it as an argument into the <input> tag at the server side.